# Wildfly Connection refused for url with DNS name

Tags: wildfly

I have a Wildfly 16 instance running on a test server. This instance can be reached successfully via the host name and the IP address of the server. In addition, there is a DNS entry for the server similar to `test.mydomain.internal`. The server does not respond to the DNS name (example url: `http://test_instance.mydomain.internal:8080/test/`). The connection is refused.

What do I have to set in the standalone.xml so that I can also get a connection via the DNS name?

-update-
The sample url has been adjusted to clarify the problem in the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It had nothing to do with the settings in the Wildfly. The DNS entry had underlines in the name. SOAPUI and two other programs had a problem with that.

Comment: Question has been updated